# Index every field in a DB

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-design, spreadsheet

I have an application that basically functions like a grid where a user can view data and sort/filter by any of the columns. It's a very small amount of data (~200K rows / 50MB), but too big to comfortably fit in the browser and do it in javascript.

The crudest/simplest approach I've thought of is to store it in mysql table with an index on every single column (yes, **every** column). The database/table is about 99% read / 1% write, so I'm not too concerned if the insert times go up by 100x or so.

Is there any downside of doing the above? What kinds of things should I be concerned about? Are there any better (server-side) approaches for doing something like this?

Comment: It will take up a lot more space.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that should be ok -- the DB is about 5MB and I think I have about 100GB for the DB and no other usage other than this application for the time being.

Comment: since multi-column indexs will benefit multiple criteria and factorially grow the problem space look out for the slow queries and see what multi-column values can be done. Lucky you have a small dataset.

Comment: Indexes aren't as effective on columns that don't have many distinct values.  Columns that only have a few different values probably respond better with a table scan rather than an index.

Comment: @danblack -- right. What might be a better data structure/storage for what I'm trying to do? I'm trying to get all queries in under 50ms or so.

Comment: Set the long_query_time=0.05 and enable slow query log and look at queries ([pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html)). [General index principles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) - order of index matters a lot, e.g. constant ref (WHERE X=const) before range (X BETWEEN yconst AND zconst). Get a [use EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) and you'll quickly get a grasp of what indexes queries can/cannot use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are "words", toss them all into a single column, separated by spaces.  Then add a single `FULLTEXT` index just on that column.  If you have other non-'word' columns, you may need to index them, too.

Caveat:  `FULLTEXT` has several limitations.  And benefits (such as singular/plural).

Presumably, you will refuse to show anything unless the do some filtering?  Don't tell me you want to let the user paginate through 200K rows!

You have not said whether they can filter on multiple columns.

You should *construct* the query in your app code.  The syntax for fulltext is different than equality and different than range tests.

If you are tempted by the problematic EAV schema design, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

I have rambled on; I could be more focused if you gave us some clues of the data and the queries.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    ...
    all_words TEXT NOT NULL,
    LastUpdated DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ...
    FULLTEXT(all_words)
)

SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(all_words) AGAINST ('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC
    LIMIT 50;
```

(Note:  Since only one index is used, and FULLTEXT has priority, an index on `LastUpdated` would not be useful *for this example*.)

Comment: thanks for these tips. I'm doing something like the `FULLTEXT` idea (combining all the columns), but how would that work for a sort? For example, I'll have a `LastUpdated` field and a user can view the last 50 items by lastUpdated...so each of the columns they can sort by and get a limit 50 (maybe paginate out to 1k results if they really want to -- 20 pages.)

Comment: @David542 - I added an example.